# I'm trying to find this element using href value, but selenium is unable to get this value as of now

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Current value of href for the login button on this website: https://www.firmex.com is provided below:

```html
<a href="https://login.firmex.com/?utm_campaign=login_button_on_firmex&amp;utm_source=firmex.com&amp;utm_medium=login_button%20&amp;_ga=2.239553475.1528002918.1522096243-201959362.1514578998" >
```

What would be the correct xpath for this href. I have used the following value:

```java
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='https://login.firmex.com/?utm_campaign=login_button_on_firmex&amp;utm_source=firmex.com&amp;utm_medium=login_button%20&amp;_ga=2.239553475.1528002918.1522096243-201959362.1514578998']")).click();
```

Any inputs would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this as a xpath locator to locate the login button for this website:

```
xpath = //a[@class='button login']
```

This should remain consistent unlike the href that would change as it apparently is appending the GA cookie value (_ga=something) in the href value.

Thanks!

Comment: Just to be a bit more error proof I would suggest the following xpath expression: `//nav[@id='site-navigation']/a[@class='button login']` as the navigation pane seems to have solid id.

Comment: Thanks @Bence Kaulics...this worked perfectly well. Much appreciate your help :)